# How to know border values for cut function in R?

Tags: r, cut, categorical-data

How to know what were the cut values (borders) generated by cut function in R if I did not specify any borders and just wrote the number of divisions needed?

```
complexes_data2$FlatPlanAmount <-  cut(complexes_data2$FlatPlanAmount, 3,labels = FALSE)
```

What are the border values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says, in the first sentence of section Details, the following. My emphasis.

> Details
> When breaks is specified as a single number, **the range of the data is divided into breaks pieces of equal length**, and then the outer limits are moved away by 0.1% of the range to ensure that the extreme values both fall within the break intervals.

So, compute the range length with `range` and `diff` and divide it by the number of breaks. Add multiples of this value to `min` of the vector to be broken to get the break points.

First test data.

```
set.seed(2021)
x <- runif(100, 0, 10)
y <- cut(x, 3, labels = FALSE)
```

Now compute the breaks.

```
brks <- min(x) + (1:2)*(diff(range(x)) / 3)
brks
#[1] 3.428711 6.690577

z <- cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, brks, Inf), labels = FALSE)
identical(y, z)
#[1] TRUE
```

This is a function doing it for any value of `x` and `breaks`.

```
where <- function(x, breaks, na.rm = TRUE){
  min(x, na.rm = na.rm) + seq_len(breaks)[-breaks]*(diff(range(x, na.rm = na.rm)) / breaks)  
}

where(x, 3)
#[1] 3.428711 6.690577
```